# Ubuntu, iSCSI LIO listen on any IPv4

Tags: ubuntu, ip, iscsi

I've installed targetcli from repo on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I'm trying to figure out how to make the service listen on any (0.0.0.0) address.

Trying to setup 0.0.0.0 specific gives me an error:

```
IP address does not exist: 0.0.0.0
```

Is it possible to configure targetcli to listen on any address? Alternatively, would it be achievable by iptables?

Comment: I've found the "free branch" version of targetcli which default behavior is to listen on any addresses. I'll give it a try. https://github.com/agrover/targetcli-fb

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly then here is solution,try this **"iscsi/iqn.2003-01.org.setup.lun.test/tpgt1/ set attribute authentication=0 demo_mode_write_protect=0 generate_node_acls=1 cache_dynamic_acls=1"**
This will allow you to access your iscsi LUN from any initiator.

Comment: Not quite the solution i was looking for. The part i was looking for, was to allow the server to listen on any IP adresses (0.0.0.0) like you see on many other services on linux. This should be setup under the portal-part of targetcli. But anyway the free branch version solved this by listening on any addresses by default.